# onclick function executed even when i clicked some other event

Tags: javascript, jquery

//in my javascript

```
$('.search_fields').live('click',"#gomsearch",function()
{
    alert('Go button clicked');
});
```

// Contents that loads via ajax

```
<div class="search_fields">
   <select id="sortBasedOn">
      <option value="value1">value1</option>
      <option value="value2">value2</option>
      <option value="value2">value3</option>
   </select>
   <input type="button" id="gomsearch" value="Go"/>
</div>
```

My problem is the **alert function** get invoked even when i clicked on the selectbox. i dont know hoe to figure it out. help me

Comment: And what you are expecting.

Comment: Do you want it to alert when you click on the div or the select or the option???

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand how anything happened at all. That syntax simply won't work with `live`: it expects precisely two parameters...

Comment: @Baadshah He wants the alert to show only when he clicks the button, but it's also showing when he clicks the dropdown.  It's quite clear :)

Comment: Somebody voted to close this question because *"It's not about programming"* ????  I'd love to see an explanation of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use `on()` method `live()` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/), as @Arun P Johny noticed you must use the document scope followed by a selector: http://jsfiddle.net/VyKPf/1/

```
$(document).on('click',".search_fields #gomsearch",function(){
    alert('Go button clicked');
});
```

Comment: verify your code, you pasted the function declaration wrong, it lacks {} symbols

Comment: Ok, the problem is with th Ajax loading

Comment: Worth mentioning that since the ajax response will be loaded into an element on the page, the code above should really reference that element instead of `document`.

Answer (score 1):

`.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7.

Use either [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) depending on your jQuery version. `.on()` is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You  need to add the event handler to document(or to the container to which the `search_fields` element is added) because `.search_fields` element also is loaded dynamically

```
$(document).on('click',"#gomsearch",function(){
    alert('Go button clicked');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#gomsearch').click(function(){
   alert('Go button clicked');
}):
```

use click function on button ID!

Answer (score 0):

Ah , i think the problem ist that the button is loaded, so use this in success of ajax:

```
$('.search_fields').on('click',"#gomsearch",function(){
    alert('Go button clicked');
});
```

Comment: or how do your load looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method as [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated.

```
$(document).on('click',"#gomsearch",function(){
    alert('Go button clicked');
});
```

Moreover your syntax for `.live()` is wrong.

```
$(parent).live(child-to-bind, event, handler) //would have worked.
```